# Reduxframework: can't get values from a post selected by a select field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, redux-framework

I have a **dropdown select field to select a custom posttype within the woocommerce product edit screen** and need to **output the ID of this selected post**.

This code works on my frontend but having issues to get it working with other plugins (here wplister).If i hardcode the selected post ID all works fine.

```
function psg_table_frontend_shortcode($atts, $content = null) { 

global $psg_global; 


/* START creating HTML Object */    
ob_start();
?>
<p>
<?php 
echo "The ID of the selected sizing Guide (cpt) inside the Product  : " .$psg_global['psg-selected-sizing-guide-on-productpage'];
?>
</p>

$output = ob_get_clean();   
/* END creating HTML Object */

return $output; 
}

add_shortcode('psg_frontend', 'psg_table_frontend_shortcode');
```

Spoke to the support of wplister but they said it is probably an issue with the reduxframwork and the global variable.

Any idea?

Comment: Is the select field a redux framework field? `$psg_global['psg-selected-sizing-guide-on-productpage']` is probably an array, perhaps if loop through it with a `foreach` you might be able to get the ID.

Answer (score 0):

if you are in a function, who knows if your psg_global is even in scope yet... so try this:

```
$psg_global= get_option( 'psg_global'); // or whatever your opt name is
$productpage = $psg_global['psg-selected-sizing-guide-on-productpage']; 

echo $productpage;
```

also, might want to use 'psg_selected_sizing_guide_on_productpage' with underscores instead of 'psg-selected-sizing-guide-on-productpage' because that way you can do this:

```
extract($psg_global)
```

and all your vars would be in scope. 
for example:

```
echo $psg_selected_sizing_guide_on_productpage
```